# Convergence in $L_p$, Vitali's theorem, and convergence in measure

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

Working a measure theory question for practice from Bartle.

Assume that

1. $(X,\mathbb{X},\mu)$ is a finite measure space
2. $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L_{p}(X,\mathbb{X},\mu)$
3. $\varphi$ is a real-valued continuous function on the real line s.t. there exists a positive number K with $\vert\varphi(t)\vert<K\vert t\vert$ if $\vert t\vert>K$

Claim: $\varphi\circ f_{n}\rightarrow\varphi\circ f$ in $L_{p}(X,\mathbb{X},\mu)$

My approach thus far has been to use the Vitali convergence theorem. I haven't been able to show that $\varphi\circ f_{n}\rightarrow\varphi\circ f$ in measure without using the continuous mapping theorem. However, Bartle's book doesn't include this theorem so either

1. I'm not supposed to use the Vitali theorem since we can't prove the convergence in measure without the continuous mapping theorem.
2. There's a way to prove convergence in measure without the continuous mapping theorem.

I'm a little lost with how to proceed.

Comment: Basically, this can be shown with the estimate $|\int \varphi(f(x))-\varphi(f_n(x))|\leq K\int |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ (in the case $p=1$). And since your measure space is finite for any $p>1$. Or is this the theorem you want to avoid?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 How would one show the convergence in $L_{1}$ from that estimate? How'd you derive that estimate? If looks like that estimate would allow me to not have to use an argument based upon the Vitali convergence theorem.

Comment: Also, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Interesting. I guess the part I'm struggling with then is how the third assumption implies Lipschitz continuity. If you're claiming that we can use Lipschitz continuity outside $[-K,K]$ then did you mean to write $\int_{\lbrace x\in X: \vert f(x)\vert,\vert f_{n}(x)\vert>K\rbrace}\vert\varphi\circ f-\varphi\circ f_{n}\vert<K\int_{\lbrace x\in X: \vert f(x)\vert,\vert f_{n}(x)\vert>K\rbrace}\vert f- f_{n}\vert$ for your estimate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you are absolutely right. We don't need Lipschitz continuity. However, as you suggested Vitali's theorem (or sometimes a generalized Lebesgue's theorem) is applicable.

So the measure space $X$ is finite. Since $f_n\to f$ in $L$ we find that, for a subsequence, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for a.e. $x$. By continuity of $\varphi$ we find for that subsequence $$g_n(x):=\varphi(f_n(x))\to \varphi(f(x))=:g(x)$$.

We shoe that $g(x)\in L^1(X)$. This implies $|g(x)|<\infty$ a.e. in $X$ (if note the integral is necessarily unbounded).

$$|g(x)|=|\varphi(f(x))|\leq \max_{t\in[-K,K]}+ K|f(x)|$$
Integration yields
$$\int_X |g(x)| \leq \int C+K|f(x)|\leq C_1(1+||f||_1)<\infty.$$

Furthermore, the last estimate yields uniform integrability since $||f_n||<C_2$ uniformly in $n$.

To get from the subsequence to the full sequence we use the following

$\mathbf{Lemma}$. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $x_n,x\in X$ be given. Then there holds: $x_n\to x\Leftrightarrow$ for every subsequence $n'$ of $n$ there is a further subsequence $n''$ of $n'$ such that $x_{n''}\to x$.

$\mathbf{Proof}$ The implication is obvious. Hence, for the other statement, assume that $x_n\not\to x$. But this means, that there is some $\varepsilon >0$ and a subsequence $n'$ such that $d(x_{n'},x)\geq \varepsilon$ for all $n'$. Due to our assumption there is a subsequence $n''$ of $n'$ such that $d(x_{n''},x)<\varepsilon$ for large $n''$. Contradiction.

Comment: Hmm. The only thing I'd wonder about is that it looks like you're using Lipschitz continuity in your reasoning about the 2nd and 3rd terms. What if our function $\varphi$ is $\sqrt(\vert x\vert-1)$ when $\vert x\vert\geq 1$ and zero otherwise? In this case, $\varphi(x)\leq\vert x\vert$ but $\varphi$ isn't Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: sorry, I updated the answer :)

Comment: it looks like this definitely shows that $\varphi\circ f_{n_{i}}\rightarrow\varphi\circ f$ where $f_{n_{i}}$ is the subsequence of $f_{n}$ that converges a.e. to f. However, how do we know that the rest of the sequence converges to f in $L_{p}$? Is there a uniqueness theorem I'm forgetting about?

Comment: No, not a uniqueness but a really elementary result. It's sometimes referred to as Cauchy's result: We consider a metric space. If $g_n$ is a sequence such that for every subsequence of $g_n$ there exist a further subsequence such that $g_{n''}\to g$ for some $g$ in the metric space. Then already $g_n\to g$. (Proof by contradiction). Now above result can be applied to every sub-, subsubsequence of $f_n$

Comment: can we argue that though? It seems that we've made a convergence argument about a SPECIFIC subsequence and not an arbitrary subsequence. I hope I'm not asking a totally stupid question :)

Comment: I just added the lemma.

Comment: Ah, so you just apply the argument to every subsequence to find the further subsequence. I officially feel like an idiot, ha ha. Thanks for all your hard work!